# Java Spring Boot: How to access local WSDL instead of a Public WSDL URL?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, wsdl

I have been using a public WSDL URL to make a call to our customer. Now the customer decided to hide the public WSDL URL and I have been asked to use a local WSDL that I need to deploy on my own server.

I'm using Java Spring Boot and here's my previous code to call the public WSDL URL:

```
    try { 
            SaajSoapMessageFactory messageFactory= new SaajSoapMessageFactory(MessageFactory.newInstance());
            messageFactory.afterPropertiesSet();
            WebServiceTemplate webServiceTemplate = new WebServiceTemplate( messageFactory);
            Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller(); 
            marshaller.setContextPath(appConfig.SOAP_PKG);  
            marshaller.afterPropertiesSet(); 
            webServiceTemplate.setMarshaller(marshaller);
            webServiceTemplate.setUnmarshaller(marshaller);
            webServiceTemplate.afterPropertiesSet();  
            WebServiceMessageSender messageSender = this.webServiceMessageSender();  
            webServiceTemplate.setMessageSender(messageSender);  
            try { 
                response = webServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(soapURL, request, new WebServiceMessageCallback() {
                     
                    @Override
                    public void doWithMessage(WebServiceMessage message) {
                        try {
                            SoapHeader soapHeader = ((SoapMessage) message).getSoapHeader();
                            Map mapRequest = new HashMap(); 
                            mapRequest.put("loginuser", soapUsername);
                            mapRequest.put("loginpass", soapPassword); 
 
                            StrSubstitutor substitutor = new StrSubstitutor(mapRequest, "%(", ")");
                            String finalXMLRequest = substitutor.replace(appConfig.SOAP_HEADER); 
                            StringSource headerSource = new StringSource(finalXMLRequest);  
                            Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
                            transformer.transform(headerSource, soapHeader.getResult());   
                            
                            
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            logger.error("Error while invoking session service :", e.getMessage() );  
                        }
                    }
                });
            }catch (SoapFaultClientException e){
                logger.error("Error while invoking session service : " + e.getMessage()); 
            }

....
```

How am I supposed now to replace "**soapURL**" which is the public WSDL URL used in marshalSendAndReceive with the local wsdl?

Comment: A SOAP API exists out of two things, the API itself and the WSDL which contains the schema. If you say that the customer hid the WSDL URL, do you mean they hid the entire API or just the schema-part (the WSDL)? If they hid the entire API, then you have to write the entire API by yourself and point the `soapURL` to that. If they only hid the WSDL, that means that the `soapURL` should still work. It only means that if you rely on generated classes based on the WSDL, that you have to generate them based on your own WSDL. If that's the case, you have to show us the code for generating classes.

Comment: Previously I generated the class using pom.xml / maven-jaxb2-plugin. For the new local wsdl, I generated the classes from SOAP UI, generating code using JAXB.

Answer (score 0):

I used wsd2ljava to generate the sources in eclipse as shown below.

```
             <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.12</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-sources</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <sourceRoot>${project.build.directory}/generated/cxf</sourceRoot>
                            <wsdlOptions>
                                <wsdlOption>
                                    <wsdl>${basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl/XXX.wsdl</wsdl>
                                    <wsdlLocation>classpath:wsdl/XXX.wsdl</wsdlLocation>
                                </wsdlOption>
                            </wsdlOptions>
                            <fork>always</fork>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

Java classes have been created. What is the next step after generating all the classes? Shall I create a CXF client configuration?